# wkhtmltopdf not working in php script

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I would like to use the wkhtmltopdf for HTML to PDF conversion.

When I have tried to convert it via linux terminal, it works fine.

But when I have tried with the php script it does not work.

I am trying execute the binary directly.

here is the code I am trying with PHP.

```
exec('/home/binary_loc/wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com /home/user/output.pdf');
```

My binary is at the same folder where "index.php" exist.

I have tried to fetch the version of wkhtmltopdf binary with PHP, then it return the version.

But i don't able to understand why not it work to execute with php for pdf.

Here is code for version check using php.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$cmd = "./wkhtmltopdf --version";
$t = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $t;
exit()
```

Do anyone has solution regarding it??

I want this because this will work in the shared hosting too. No need to install the wkhtmltopdf in the server.

Comment: Have you checked the binary for system bits, Like 32 or 64

Comment: Yes I have checked it. Its 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

Define the complete path to the wkhtmltopdf executable and the complete path to the output folder.

To debug try something like this:

```
shell_exec("/home/binary_loc/wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com /home/user/output.pdf > /home/user/debug.log 2>&1");
```

pipe the error in a file

Comment: I have tried that one too. Is there any way to debug it?

Comment: You can pipe the error in a file. Otherwise take the complete Path and run that under your web user. Perhaps you have not enough rights.

Comment: And you can check your apache error log. Normally you can see the wk output in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Exec probably doesn't have permission to execute the file. PHP usually runs as either `apache` or `nobody`, rather than your user account. You'll have to make sure the execute bit is set for whatever user it runs under. You can use `chmod 755 wkhtmltopdf` from the directory it's under, to grant read and execute to all users.

Note that on some shared hosting, `exec()` is disabled. Check with your host to make sure you have access to it.